# The conditional request failed without conditional condition in Code

Tags: java, https, amazon-dynamodb, runtime-error

I am using Dynamodb to save my new user data, but I got some ConditionalCheckFailedException while saving the data.

I checked online and got , like if we are using some condition then there might be a chance that we are conflicting with the data.

So I refactor my code and remove the `saveExpression.setConditionalOperator(ConditionalOperator.AND)` condition.

But After that I am getting the same issue:

```
{
  "errorCode": 500,
  "message": "The conditional request failed (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ConditionalCheckFailedException; Request ID: LN5P87FREI8SP1EIG4C9O60OUVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9LSMANOG; Proxy: null)"
}
```

I want to know what are the other factor that raised this issue ? I know its difficult to suggest because I have limited code to share. But Any help will be helpful here.

Attaching my DB code :

```
  @Override
    public Optional<Item> addUser(@NonNull final Item userItem) {
        DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpression = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
        Map<String, ExpectedAttributeValue> expectedAttributes =
                Map.of("UserId", new ExpectedAttributeValue(false));
        saveExpression.setExpected(expectedAttributes);
        super.save(userItem, saveExpression);
        return super.load(Item.class, userItem.getUserId())
```

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB has two syntaxes for conditional updates. The older one is `Expected` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.Expected.html) and the newer one is `ConditionExpression` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html).

You request still uses "Expected", so it is indeed a conditional expression. Clearly the condition you expressed in this "Expected" is not true in your use case. I don't have enough data on your workload to know why.

Comment: My concern here is, Even If I remove this "expectedAttributes "syntax and only used save method , I still got this issue.... weird thing

Comment: AnyOne, it will be great for any suggestion?